# rsync files older than 7 days to password protected server

Tags: linux, bash, backup, rsync

I am attempting to use a combination of find and rsync to backup all files in a directory older than 7 days, as a part of a weekly backup script to a password protected server.

I am using `find /local/directory/path -mtime +10 -exec rsync {} username@serverhost:/server/directory/path` with no luck. I receive the error `find: missing argument to -exec`

Is there something I am missing or could someone point out the error? On the other hand, is this the best way to backup all the files that satisfies the requirement while entering the server's password only once?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to end `rsync`'s `-exec` with an escaped semi-colon: `\;`

So `find /local/directory/path -mtime +10 -exec rsync {} username@serverhost:/server/directory/path \;`

Though that will spam `rsync` commands. Perhaps do something like https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87022/140671 instead so it only does 1.